# after uploading images in home page in grid format, site is not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

We used below code to display images from "TOP OFFERS" to "TOP Brands" in home page.

site is not looking responsive in home page from " top categories" to top charactar " section only means images are stretching in smaller screens

code : http://pastebin.com/qqygnYbf

```html
<div class="offers ">
  <br />
  <div class="horizontal_line">
    <div>
      <span>TOP OFFERS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br /> 
  <a href="20-off.html">
    <img class="fluid2" style="max-width: 23%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/20c.jpg"}}" alt="" />
  </a> 
  <a href="50-off.html">
    <img class="fluid3" style="max-width: 50%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/50f.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
  </a> 
  <a href="10-off.html"><img class="fluid22" style="max-width: 23%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/10c.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
  </a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="horizontal_line">
    <div>
      <span>TOP CATEGORIES</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div class=" grid_24">
  <div class=" grid_12 alpha">
    <a href="girls-toys/soft-toys.html">
      <img class="fluid5" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/sof33b.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class=" grid_6">
    <a href="boys-toys/remote-control-toys.html">
      <img class="fluid6" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/ele33.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a> 
    <a href="girls-toys/arts-crafts.html"><img class="fluid7" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/art33.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class=" grid_6 omega">
    <a href="boys-toys/bikes-trikes-ride-ons.html">
      <img class="fluid8" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/rid33.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
    </a> 
    <a href="boys-toys/educational-learning-toys.html">
      <img class="fluid9" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/edu33.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" grid_24">
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="horizontal_line">
    <div>
      <span>FEATURED PRODUCTS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class=" grid_6 alpha">
    <a href="darling-bear-pink-25-inch.html">
      <img class="fluid11" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/fea1a.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a> 
    <a href="heavy-truck-machine-super-power.html">
      <img class="fluid12" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/fea2.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_12">
    <a href="top-speed-car-black-blue.html">
      <img class="fluid13" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/fea5.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_6 omega">
    <a href="boys-toys/jana-police-jeep.html">
      <img class="fluid14" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/fea3.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
    </a>
    <a href="model-car-remote-control-762.html">
      <img class="fluid15" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/fea4.jpg"}}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="horizontal_line">
  <div class=" grid_24">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="horizontal_line">
      <div>
        <span>TOP CHARACTER</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class=" grid_6 alpha">
      <a href="shop-by-character/barbie.html">
        <img class="fluid17" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/bar.jpg"}}" alt="" />
      </a> 
      <a href="shop-by-character/mickey-mouse.html">
        <img class="fluid18" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/mic.jpg"}}" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" grid_6">
      <a href="shop-by-character/doreman.html">
        <img class="fluid19" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/dor.jpg"}}" alt="" />
      </a>
      <a href="shop-by-character/chota-beam.html">
        <img class="fluid20" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/cho.jpg"}}" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" grid_12 omega"><a href="shop-by-character/spider-man.html">
      <img class="fluid21" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/sup.jpg"}}" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" grid_25">
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="horizontal_line">
    <div>
      <span>TOP BRANDS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br /> 
  <a href="20-off.html"> 
    <img class="fluid51" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/brand1.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
  </a> 
  <a href="50-off.html">
    <img class="fluid52" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/brand6.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
  </a> 
  <a href="10-off.html">
    <img class="fluid53" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/brand7.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
  </a>
  <br /> 
  <a href="20-off.html"> 
    <img class="fluid54" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/brand4.jpg"}}" alt="" />
  </a>
  <a href="50-off.html">
    <img class="fluid55" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/brand8.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
  </a> 
  <a href="10-off.html">
    <img class="fluid56" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category/brand9.jpg"}}" alt="" /> 
  </a>
</div>
```

But the site is not looking responsive, in mobile and tablets it's not looking well.

Comment: Post your code in the answer because your links later can be deprecated. So we have the code for future references/users.

Comment: thanks , but i don't know how to put code properly here.....

Comment: What have you tried? Please try to do some research and attempt to solve the issue by yourself first. StackOverflow can help you if you are stuck somewhere specific, but this isn't the place to ask for advice or recommendations, and definitely not the place to ask "can you please do all my work for me?".

Comment: hi, i tried but as i am new to this, i can not able to do it, please help me to make it responsive.....

Comment: @learner You should format your question to be a bit more specific. Which exact thing is not looking good? Does it give any bad behaviour that you want to avoid? Asking for example "My menu no longer slides open in mobile" is way better than asking "please make it responsive". If you ask such vague questions, you will most likely be downvoted or your question will be closed.

Comment: @DarkAshelin i edited the question, please check......

Comment: @learner Still not specific enough. You should explain that the images are being deformed/do not stick to the grid. Basically explain *what exactly* is looking wrong, not just "it's not responsive" which could be a million different things. Take a look at our [How to ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DarkAshelin if i check the site in smaller devices, all images should proprly....

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is being caused by this specific CSS:

```
left: -43px; /* This tells the image to position itself outside the grid */
width: 120%; /* This makes the image too wide to fit in the grid */
min-height: 175px; /* This deforms the image because it will not be scaled properly */
```

You have custom `left`, `width` and `min-height` on all your images with the `fluid` classes. This causes the images to be deformed and to exit the grid.

So just remove this CSS and use the proper CSS that came with the theme.

Comment: visit this link : http://demo.kidsdial.com/

i did lot of changes to "top categories section", please look at that section and help me what else i have to do to make that section responsive.

Comment: @learner Can you please clarify what exactly is not responsive with it?

Comment: @learner That's because the images are in landscape-format. If you change the height the images would be stretched. How do you want the images to fit without being stretched?

Comment: yes, if i use more taller images, those images will stretch in smaller screens. i really don't have any idea 

what i have to do now, i tried with height: auto; also but it did't worked....

Comment: @learner You should think first in your head how you can solve this. Maybe by positioning the images differently.

Answer (score 0):

There a number of mis-typed elements and classes within your CSS which is then not grabbing the correct media queries from your CSS.

The class on the first Top Offers image is incorrect and should be `fluid22`, not `fluid2`.

The Top Brands container is what is breaking those images. You are using `grid_25` for that container when all the rest are `grid_24`.

Change it to look like this:

```
<div class="grid_24"></div>
```

The rest of the page just needs a little cleanup for spacing and you should be good.

Comment: top offers and top brands are looking responsiive, but the grid layout is not responsive.....

Comment: I dont fully understand what you mean by the grid layout not being responsive?

Comment: sorry  that i did't mentioned in question  : this is the link i am using to make responsive : grid layout : http://rocketmedia.com/blog/converting-website-to-responsive-design

Comment: That blog makes no sense in terms of what you are trying to achieve. There is no code, no explanation and in general, it looks like its more used as a sales pitch to get you to contact them to get work in. I would look at actual tutorial websites to achieve what you want. Saying the grid is not responsive is very vague and in most cases requires a deep knowledge of the entire css/html structure which we cant achieve here.

Comment: By looking at your demo website, You havent made the amendments ive suggested or made clear exactly what sort of design you are expecting.

Comment: if i check the site in smaller devices, all images should properly.... i tried your solution using inspect element, it did't worked, so i did't implemented .... what i have to make to look images proprly in smaller devices.....

Comment: visit this link : http://demo.kidsdial.com/

i did lot of changes to "top categories section", please look at that section and help me what else i have to do to make that section responsive.